# When I override the getter, should I release the object in dealloc?

Tags: ios

I have read some source code from a github project.. The project uses lazy loading, and override the getter to make sure saving resources.And release it in dealloc..The code like this:

```
-(XHMessageTableView *)messageTableView {
if (!_messageTableView) {
    _messageTableView = [[XHMessageTableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _messageTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    _messageTableView.dataSource = self;
    _messageTableView.delegate = self;
    _messageTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _messageTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}
return _messageTableView;
```

}

in init:

```
[self.view addSubviews:self.messageTableView];
```

in dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {
_messageTableView = nil;}
```

in ARC , is it necessary to set the property nil if override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

As long as no retain cycles were created, setting the variable to nil should not be necessary.

However to have a better idea as to why the author may have felt it was necessary to release the `tableView` on `dealloc`, I'd have to take a closer look at the code. Maybe they felt that the `tableView`'s `delegate` or `dataSource` were held strongly, which is not the case for `UITableView` but may be the case for the implementation of their class, or maybe a retain cycle was created somewhere else in the code.

Comment: awesome answer... I agree with your idea. The author may think something was held strongly.. But a good design is to find where the problem is, and fix up  rather than set it nil manually...